# Front-end/back-end technique for using JQuery deferred progress and notify methods

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my website I have a button for a user to click that says "Sync Objects". Pressing this button will call my server to initiate a process where I call an external system to get all of the users objects, and save each one to my database.  While this is happening, I would like to let the user know how many objects have synced so far.

This seems like the right use case for JQuery's `notify` and `progress` methods, which I have never used before.

My first thought is to:

Make an ajax to start the sync process, returning promise A. After that process starts, I make a separate ajax call, returning promise B, every 2 seconds, to a separate endpoint that returns the total number of objects currently in my database for that user. I use that value to update the total sync count shown to the user.

This doesn't seem like the right way to do this, since I'm basically treating the sync process and the checking for progress as two separate promises.

How do I correctly use JQuery's `notify` and `progress` methods to keep the user updated on the progress of the sync job?

Comment: Without implementing some sort of websocket solution, you're pretty much on the right track as far your approach. The only thing is if you're using an "external system" to save each user object, the client won't have any knowledge of when these individual bits are successfully being added. To pull off a progress indicator, I think you'll need to $.ajax POST each user object from your JS and utilize callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Note, Utilizing pattern below , could wrap `dfd.progress(fn)` portion in web worker message event , initiated by call to server , message posted back to page from server during retrieval and processing of objects

Try

html

```
<button>Sync Objects</button>
<progress></progress>
<div></div>
```

js

```
// call an external system to get all of the users objects , 
// `requests` : users objects
var requests = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
// save user objects to database , `uo`
var uo = [];
// text notification 
var pgx = $("div");
// `progress` element notification
var progress = $("progress");
// set `progress` `max` to `requests` `length`
progress.attr({"max":requests.length, "value":0});
// jquery `deferred` object
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
// do progress stuff
dfd.progress(function(msg) {
  $(this).html(msg + " objects processed");
  progress.get(0).value = uo.length; 
    if (uo.length === requests.length) {
      // resolve `dfd` when all `requests` complete
      dfd.resolve(uo)
    }
});
// do stuff when all `uo` retrieved , processed
dfd.done(function(data) {
  pgx.append("<br><pre>" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
});

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
    $.each(requests, function(key, value) {
        // call server to initiate a process
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.post("/echo/json/"
                   , {
                       json:JSON.stringify(value)
            }) 
            .always(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                if (textStatus !== "success") {
                  // handle `error` response
                  console.log(textStatus, jqxhr)
                } else {
                  // save "user object" `data` to "database" `uo`
                  uo.push(data);
                  // notify completed object retrievals , processing ,
                  // with `pgx` as `dfd` context
                  dfd.notifyWith(pgx, [uo.length])
                }
            })
         }, key * Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000))            
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/bckmm5zx/